# Github: use my freshly commited new features while waiting for my pull requests to be merge

Tags: github

Contributing to a public project on Github, I made a fork.
Then I created a new branch (b1) to commit some features and I sent a pull request.
Then I did the same for completely different features: create a new branch (b2 from master), commit some modifications and send a pull request.
While I am waiting for my 2 pull requests to be accepted, I would like to use those modifications which are in branches b1 and b2.
What is the best/easy way to achieve that?

- Merging b1 and b2 into master? But master won't be the same as upstream/master and if I create new branched they will include changes from b1 and b2
- Create a new temporary branch to merge b1 and b2? But I need to keep this branch up to date with master until all my pull requests will be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Create a new temporary branch to merge b1 and b2?

Yes: you should not modify a branch in use in the original repo, and always isolate your work in a dedicated branch.

If at any time you want to keep that new integration branch (for b1+b2) up-to-date compared to `upstream/master`, simply rebase it on top of a refreshed `upstream/master`:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add upstream /url/of/original/repo

git checkout b1_b2
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```